# How do I find the MAC address programatically on IRIX?

Tags: c, unix, irix

How do I find the MAC address of a network card on IRIX? I'd rather not shell out to something that displays it and parse the output.

I'm coding C.

Methods that require root access are acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <net/raw.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <net/soioctl.h> 
#include <sys/ioctl.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

struct ifreq ifdat;
int s;

s = socket (PF_RAW, SOCK_RAW, RAWPROTO_SNOOP);
strcpy (ifdat.ifr_name, "en0");
ioctl (s, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifdat);

...
```

Clean it up a little, and ifdat should contain your MAC address.

Comment: Success (ifdat.enaddr). I hereby crown you king of IRIX. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about programmatically, but you could try `/etc/nvram eaddr`, I suppose you could `exec()` that.

Comment: I'd prefer not to shell out, but at least it works. Thanks. Does this mean that all network cards have the same MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms (Linux, for example) `ioctl()` allows to obtain MAC address. You need to check on IRIX as `ioctl()` is platform-dependent.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for something a bit more specific than that. I've looked at ioctl() and sysctl() already, but nothing sticks out to me.

Comment: Did you check possible ioctl() request in ioctl headers?